# How do I set up MongoDB so that it is exposed to my local windows network?

Tags: python, windows, mongodb, networking, pymongo

I just need to expose one windows computer's MongoDB database to all the others on the same Windows network.

I searched stack overflow but nobody seems to be specifically addressing this issue. What I've done so far is gone to the mongoDB Windows computer and exposed port 27017. I also went to the config file of mongoDB and set it to [ 0.0.0.0, ::]. Then I went to computer number two and was unable to get the database from computer number one.

I want to do this because I have code that I wrote which pulls data from the database but I can't until I figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your [mongod.cfg file](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/), replace "bindIp: 127.0.0.1" with "bindIpAll: true

```
# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIpAll: true
```

Ensure your firewall allows traffic on port 27017, and then restart your MongoDB server in Windows Service Manager.

You can test remote connectity just by typing:

```
mongo <hostname>
```

on a remote machine.

Comment: I followed your steps but was unable to solve it.  I made the changes to the config file but still received message it was " WARNING: This server is bound to localhost.
2019-08-29T11:14:51.901-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Remote systems will be unable to connect to this server."  I was only able to get it to bind to all interfaces with running the command "mongo -- --bind_ip_all".  Even after this correction, when I go to the PC #2, I try to access mongo but it doesn't work.  In PC#2, I tried typing: "mongo 192.168.42.2:27017" but it said "mongo is not recognized as an exter.."

Comment: After installing MongoDB Community Edition on PC #2, and after adding the /bin/ filepath to the PATH variable in Windows System Environment Variables did it work with the command "mongo <hostname>:27017" (no quotes).  Thank you Belly Buster!